# How to open a file in the folder from Activities search

Tags: 20.04

In Ubuntu, when I search for a file in the Activities window, I get a list of files. When I click on it (or press Enter) the file opens. But how can I open it in the enclosing folder? Can I do it with a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is using `shift+tab` to highlight the `files` on the left side of the result in the activities and then press enter. When the Files window pops up, using `Ctrl+Alt+o` you can open the containing folder of the file.

Although, I believe you are looking for a simpler solution. Hope we can find one...